# Flutter web Need a sample on how to pass and show image in generated PDF using PDF package

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to generate PDF in Flutter web using https://pub.dev/packages/pdf package.
Everything is fine, except images, they won't work. 
I tried several ways, but without success. 
So my question is - how to pass and show image in PDF in Flutter web?

1 way throws chrome exception 
 Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 876: 876

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' as w;
import 'package:inspections/models/inspection.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' ;

Future<Document> generateDocument(
    PdfPageFormat format,  Uint8List  logo) async {
  final Document doc = Document(
    title: 'name',
    author: 'author',
  );
  PdfImage sample = PdfImage(doc.document, image: logo, width: 100, height: 100, alpha: true);

....
```

2 way
does not return anything:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' as w;

ByteData byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/image.png');
  var k = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  var temp = await pdfImageFromImageProvider(
          pdf: doc.document,
          image: w.MemoryImage(k));
```

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me in Flutter web:

```
    ByteData imageData;   

 rootBundle
         .load('assets/XYZ.jpg')
         .then((data) => setState(() => this.imageData = data));

...

 final image = PdfImage.jpeg(
      pdf.document,
      image: imageData.buffer.asUint8List()
 );
...
pw.Image(image)
```